# require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php, composer-php

I know, this question has been asked many times, but it seems the problem is different or I am missing something.

I have the following structure: `/var/www/html/website/class/useofautoload.php`

The `vendor` folder is at: `/var/www/html/website/vendor` and it has necessary folders and `autoload.php` file.

Things checked:

1. [Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962633/failed-opening-required-vendor-autoload-php)
2. Have relative path
3. done: `composer install`
4. done: `composer update`

Still, I don't know why I am getting this error.

Note: I have installed the composer at using `sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`, will it create a problem as such?

I am using Amazon LightSail with only Ubuntu and no added stacks.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this error on my server working with Symfony 4.
In my case, it was just a matter of absolute path :

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php
```

In fact, I've remarked that it was used the same way in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you did not make a correct relative path. try: `../../vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: @Shared Soni what do you mean? is it the err message?